# Oracle compare query results with multiple joins against a table

Tags: sql

I need to compare query results against a table.  I have the following query.

```
select
i.person_id,
a.appellant_first_name,
a.appellant_middle_name,
a.appellant_last_name,
s.*

from CWLEGAL.individuals i inner join CWLEGAL.tblappealsdatarevisionone a
on i.casenm = a.D_N_NUMBER1 and 
   i.first_name = a.appellant_first_name and 
   i.last_name = a.appellant_last_name
inner join CWLEGAL.tblappealstosupremecourt s
on a.DATABASEIDNUMBER = s.DBIDNUMBER
order by orclid21;
```

I need to see what orclid21's in cwlegal.tblappealstosupremecourt  don't appear in the above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work.

```
select 
i.person_id,
a.appellant_first_name,
a.appellant_middle_name,
a.appellant_last_name,
s.*
from CWLEGAL.tblappealstosupremecourt s
join CWLEGAL.tblappealsdatarevisionone a
on  a.DATABASEIDNUMBER = s.DBIDNUMBER
left outer join CWLEGAL.individuals i on
i.casenm = a.D_N_NUMBER1 and 
   i.first_name = a.appellant_first_name and 
   i.last_name = a.appellant_last_name
where person_id is null
order by orclid21
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making the first inner join between i and a, the result of which you're joining with s.
Now, if you want to see which records won't join, that's known as anti-join, and in whatever database you're querying it, it may be achieved by either selecting a null result or taking those records as a new result.
Examples, with taking your query *(the whole code in the question)* as q, assuming you've kept all the needed keys in it:
Example 1:

```
with your_query as q

select s.orclid21 from q
left join CWLEGAL.tblappealstosupremecourt s
  on q.DATABASEIDNUMBER = s.DBIDNUMBER
 and s.orclid21 is null
```

Example 2:

```
with your_query as q

select s.orclid21 from q
right join CWLEGAL.tblappealstosupremecourt s
  on q.DATABASEIDNUMBER != s.DBIDNUMBER
```

Example 3:

```
with your_query as q

select s.orclid21 from CWLEGAL.tblappealstosupremecourt s
where s.DBIDNUMBER not in (select distinct q.DATABASEIDNUMBER from q)
```

Comment: Thanks Julian.  I'm not sure what I fill in for "your_query"

Comment: I want to keep the examples concise, to show the principle of making anti-join queries. I don't know your data base or tables, neither should those tables contain duplicate keys for joining. Furthermore, the your_query reference is to take what you already have as a list, and the identify the missing keys, as you requested (to my understanding). I hope this helps. Still, I'd advise you to check your database's manual for ANTI-JOIN operation.